# Need help extracting data from an array

Tags: python

I am trying to get just one row and one cell from this array but its very complex
this is the command im using:

```
xyz= supporter.get_dict_value_using_key(xyz, "return_value")
        return_value = supporter.get_dict_value_using_key(xyz, "returnValue")
abc = supporter.get_value_with_id(return_value[1],"text")
        html_logger.log(LoggerMode.INFO, "abc" + str(abc))
```

and here is the raw data from the array:

```
xyz{'result': True, 'return_value': {'returnValue': [{'row': {'hasFocus': True, 'children': [{'cell': {'foreground': 'ccccccff', 'icons': [{'icon': {'iconPath': '72hours.png'}}], 'text': '2 KCBS', 'background': '3f4650ff', 'hasFocus': False, 'hasSecondaryFocus': True, 'font': {'fontHeight': 34, 'fontName': 'ClearviewATT'}}}, {'cell': {'foreground': 'ebebebff', 'icons': [{'icon': {'iconPath': 'HD.png'}}], 'text': 'CBS 2 News at 5:00pm', 'background': '184f91ff', 'hasFocus': True, 'hasSecondaryFocus': False, 'font': {'fontHeight': 42, 'fontName': 'ClearviewATT'}}},
```

i am trying to get the text CBS 2 News at 5:00pm and assign it to abc
please help sorry if format is bad and my python level is less than beginner

Comment: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries_nested.asp) May be a good resource as well, work your way through the examples.

Comment: thanks, i have already gone through these and these do not seem related to what im trying to do. overly simplified thanks anyway.

Comment: I know its an array within an arrray or something like this but im just not sure on the format. please dont link tutorials i ve gone through them all         supporter.get_value_with_id(return_value[1][0],"text")

Comment: To make this code reproducible ([mcve]), you need to add the code that defines `supporter`, what is it and where does it come from? Include any missing import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you really want that specific row and that specific cell, you can access it like this if and only if the object structure is always the same as in the example. If the structure or the index of your required data is dynamic, you would need to find a pattern or a format to extract it.

```
abc = xyz['return_value']['returnValue'][0]['row']['children'][1]['cell']['text']
```